# Can I run a sql query containg HAVING and no GROUP BY

Tags: sql, jdbc

```
SELECT COUNT(unique(LEDGER))
FROM tablename
HAVING (COUNT(unique(LEDGER)) <= 1)
```

The above query when ran is throwing the following error java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered " "HAVING" "HAVING "" at line 1, column 44 Was expecting:

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Note that you have a trailing paren that is a syntax error -- but not causing the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean by trailing parent. And if there is a syntax error can u plz elaborate.Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you (trying) to do?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the construct is `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, not `COUNT(UNIQUE)`.  So, first try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEDGER))
FROM tablename
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LEDGER) <= 1;
```

If this does not work, use a subquery:

```
SELECT cnt
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEDGER) as cnt
      FROM tablename
     ) c
WHERE cnt <= 1;
```